# How to parallelize database inserts from python

Tags: python, multithreading, postgresql, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a script that reads from an access database and writes into a postgresql. That script handles the old data from access (missing primary and foreign keys, etc) before inserting it in postgresql database.
I would like to parallelize (make inserts onto multiple tables at the same time) the independent parts, meaning:

- group1: insert into tableA, tableB
- group2: insert into tableC, tableD, tableE

TableC is dependent (foreign keys) of TableB, which is dependent of tableA but group2 is independent of group1.

**What is the best way to achieve this using python, if even possible?**

I have tried threading, multiprocessing and concurrent.futures but seem to fail to grasp the intricacies of parallelization. My latest attempt:

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as e:
    g1 = e.submit(group1)
    g2 = e.submit(group2)
```

waiting for the first batch to be done to start another one, that depends on the first one:

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as e:
    g3 = e.submit(group3)
    g4 = e.submit(group4)
```

groups being defined as:

```
def group1():
    print('g1')
    acc_con = psycopg2.connect(host='xxx', database='old_access')
    pg_con = psycopg2.connect(host='xxx', database='new_postgre')
    tableA = transfer_tableA(acc_con.cursor(), lvs_con.cursor())
    tableB = transfer_tableB(acc_con.cursor(), lvs_con.cursor())
    pg_con.commit()
    pg_con.close()
    acc_con.close()
    return 'tableA and tableB done'
```

has no significant performance gain compared to my sequential script (which starts the transfer scripts one after the other: tA, tB, tC, tD, tE). All my attempts had no performance gain (sometimes being even slower than the sequential script).

Comment: As you've mentioned, your tableC is dependent on tableB, so tableB has to go in first so that you can use the IDs in tableC as your relations. Same holds true for tableB <--> tableA. 

Here's what I can think of, before even going to the database, add a new field to each of the tables which will hold IDs that you generate manually. You then use the generated ids in the related tables.
Do a bulk insert for each table. You can then query the relationships using the new field that you have created.

Naturally there definitely will be other(probably better) ways of doing it :)

Comment: Basically - Read from access database > add a new `id` field for each record > Read another table from access and add `id` field and the related table's id field > bulk insert into postgres tables

Comment: Yes, that is basically what I am doing. I am creating the relations during the transfer, modifying the data on the fly before inserting it.

Comment: Parallel query will not always work with inserts. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Parallel_Query . Also multi-threading is limited / not available in Python (i'm not a python person, so not 100% sure). If your tables can be inserted individually I separate your python inserts into individual scripts and you can fire them off individually and let your OS deal with multiple executions working in parallel